# Filling out 3rd party web forms

Tags: javascript, php, forms, testing, automation

How can I autofill/ submit web forms on 3rd party websites that do not expose the source code of their forms (see Spotify login page src code below)? How can I select the form fields here to input values - will I have to resort to "getElement" by JS or "tabbing through the UI"?

My research leads my to believe that Selenium2 and PHPUnit are good ways to test and ultimately automatically fill in web forms automatically. This is all assuming that I already have the values that I need in an array to fill in the form fields/ satisfy validation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="accounts" ng-csp>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="(title && (title | localize) + ' - ') + 'Spotify'">Spotify</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <base href="/">
    <link href="https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/45962e4/css/index.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">

    <script async defer src="https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/45962e4/js/index.js" sp-bootstrap></script>
    <meta ng-non-bindable sp-bootstrap-data='{"country":"US","locales":["en_US","en"],"BON":["0","0",-1691062138]}'>
  </head>
  <body ng-view></body>
</html>
```